# IsInitialized Property missing in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

- Target version: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)
- VS 2015 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.2.2
- C#
- Xaml

I try to create simple custom control. The control class derives from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls class and Custom from Windows.UI.Xaml. I need sth similar to FrameworkElement.IsInitialized Property(WPF). Unfortunately, neither Custom nor FrameworkElement don't provide this property. Does Uwp support it in some other way?

Example:

```
public class CharacterCount : Control
    {
      ...
      private void UpdatedContent()
        {
          if(this.IsInitialized) // not supported
          {
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually for custom UWP controls you're going to look for the [Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded) or [OnApplyTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_OnApplyTemplate) events on [FrameworkElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement).

See the [Object Lifetime Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement#remarks) section of the remarks.

Depending on your specific needs you could add an `IsInitialized` property that is set during one of these events.  You could even make it an attached property if you need to extend an existing set of controls.

Comment: In my case `OnApplyTemplate()` helped.